# WebView.loadDataWithBaseUrl doesn't show images

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have an HTML string of data that i parse from an ATOM Feed. Obviously there are references to images inside, that I'd like to show on a WebView. But using

> webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data,"text/html", "utf-8","");

only the text is displayed and the images are not shown.

What I am missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the `BASE URL`, you are passing the `emptry string`. As you can see in the docs [`loadDataWithBaseURL()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL) is expecting as the first parameter the `Base URL` of your `Html Data`. So what you should have is something like this :

```
  webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("www.mypage.html",data,"text/html","utf-8",null);
```

Comment: The docs say that the base URL is useful only in the case of relative URL, in this case I have an absolute URL inside the data because I am getting it from an ATOM feed. Also trying with the right BASE_URL inside doesn't change the behaviour

Comment: you should try to enable javascript if you haven't done so on your webview. also try to see if you put that data inside a html if the images are displayed.